# Next date with distinct digits

Tags: logical-deduction

The date today is 7th June 2019, or 07/06/2019 (using the English DD/MM/YYYY ordering).

When is the next date that when written in this way has all eight digits different?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Rather remarkably, I wrote down this exact puzzle in my notebook a couple of years ago to which I think the answer is

> 17/06/2345 in DD/MM/YYYY format.

Reasoning

> Notice that the first M will either be $0$ or $1$. 
>  If it is $0$ then the first D will either be $1$ or $2$ or DD will be $31$. 
>  If it is $1$ then either the second M will be $0$ or the second M will be $2$ and the day will contain a $0$. 
>  Overall, this means that $0$ and either $1$ or $2$ must be used in the DD/MM part. If we don't want to skip to the next millenium, we need the $2$ for the beginning of the year. 
>  Hence the DD/MM part requires both $0$ and $1$. 
>  After that, we focus on the nearest year possible which comes from assigning the digits $3,4,5$ in order to century, decade and digit of the year. 
>  It makes more sense to assign the $0$ to the month instead of $1$ but we cannot assign both since we cannot have a day without any of $0$, $1$ or $2$. Hence, we assign $6$ to the month and then $7$ to create the day.

Comment: I can confirm that this is also the result of writing a dumb Python program to try future dates until it finds one satisfying the given condition.

Comment: Pleasingly (but also somewhat obviously) the two days following also satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot comment yet and I know this is not what the asker meant but it is natural to ponder what is the closest date (in future or past) with that property. With a similar deduction as in the answer marked correct I came up with the date

> 25/06/1987

and in similar fashion to the next future date also the two previous days satisfy the condition.

Comment: Nice observation, and welcome!